# Update function for one to many field in odoo10

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I have to two types of fields one is many2one and another is one2many field. And in many2one field i selected workflow(full-flow, semi-flow and simplified-flow) and in one2many field related stage and status "char" types field. And i applied a function on "button field", in which i want that when i select particular workflow then related "stage" available on button field and "status" in status bar.  So, anyone can solve this problem.

My Python and XML Code is here:

**Python Code:**

work_flow_stage = fields.Many2one('stage.workflow', column='workflow', string="Type of Workflow")
stages_workflow_flow = fields.One2many('stages.workflow', 'order_id', string="Stages Workflow")
state = fields.Char("Stage")
status = fields.Char("Status")

```
@api.multi
def case_start(self, work_flow_stage, context=None):
    vals = {}
    workflow_obj = self.work_flow_stage.workflow
    print "workflow_obj: ", workflow_obj
    stage_obj = self.work_flow_stage.stages_workflow_flow
    print "workflow_obj: ", stage_obj
    for vals in stage_obj:
        print "valsssss", vals
        print "vals: stage ", vals.stage_id.state
        print "vals: status", vals.status_id
        stages_workflow_flow =  [(0, 0, {
            'work_flow_stage': vals.stage_id.state
        })]
        print "vals: stages_workflow_flow", stages_workflow_flow
```

**Xml Code:**

```
<header>
    <button name="case_start" string="Start" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
    <field name="work_flow_stage " nolabel="1" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="none"
           statusbar_colors='{"pending":"blue"}'/>
</header>
```